# Escalar uma imagem com imagick sem deformar a original

Tags: php, imagem, imagick

Um tenho uma aplicação em que o utilizador pode fazer upload de uma imagem, fazer crop e "trabalhar" a imagem, adicionando adereços etc... O meu problema é no crop porque o tamanho max do crop é sempre diferente consoante as a resolução das imagens, para combater isso eu pensei em pôr todas as imagens com a mesma resolução que também funciona mas preciso de especificar o `width` e `height` da imagem, alguma forma de só definir um deles (outras soluções são bem vindas) de maneira a nunca deformar a imagem que foi 'uploadada' pelo utilizador? Tenho este código, funciona bem:

```
$thumb = new Imagick();
$thumb->readImage('imgTest.jpg');
$thumb->resizeImage(300,3000,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
$thumb->writeImage('imgTest.jpg');
$thumb->clear();
$thumb->destroy();
```